# Как показывать элементы в RecyclerView кусками (порционно)?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

в RecyclerView передаётся около 700 элементов, на отображение которого требуется около 2-3 секунд, прежде чем оно отобразится.

Как решить данную проблему, сделав отображение по 50 элементов хотя бы (и вручную "подтягиванием" подгружать еще + 50 элементов)? Заранее спасибо!

И можно меня ткнуть также на похожие вопросы, либо нужные библиотеки для этого?

Какой код от меня требуется? адаптера?

**код адаптера:**

```
public class AllStationActivityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllStationActivityAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static int MODE_DIRECTORY = 0;
private static int MODE_FAVORITES = 1;
public boolean colorTitleStation = true;


public interface Listener {
    void onStationClicked(final Station station);
}

private final List<Station> stations = new LinkedList<>();
private Listener listener;
private int mode;
private static String descriptionInfo;
private static String descriptionInfoFinal;
private static String nameInfo;
private static String nameInfoFinal;
static MaterialStyledDialog dialog5;
public AllStationActivityAdapter() {
    stations.addAll(getStations());
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.directory_item_two, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Station station = stations.get(position);
    holder.nameView.setText(station.getName());
    holder.genre.setText(String.format("%s", station.getNetwork()));
    holder.online.setText(String.format(""+"%s", position+1));
    //holder.descriptionView.setText(String.format("%s", station.getDescription()));
    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(station.getIconUrl()).transform(new Transformation() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
            PaletteCache.generate(station.getIconUrl(), source);
            return source;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return station.getIconUrl();
        }
    }).into(holder.iconView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            final Palette palette = PaletteCache.get(station.getIconUrl());
            if (palette == null)
                return;

            final Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
            if (swatch != null) {

            }

            // ставим цвет заголовка названия
            if (!colorTitleStation){
                if (swatch != null) {
                    holder.nameView.setTextColor(swatch.getRgb());
                    colorTitleStation = false;
                }
            } else {
                colorTitleStation = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onStationClicked(station);
//                holder.itemView.startAnimation(new     CustomAnimation().AnimationItem(AllStationActivityAdapter.this));
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            descriptionInfo = String.valueOf(holder.getLayoutPosition());
            descriptionInfoFinal = stations.get(Integer.parseInt(descriptionInfo)).getDescription();
            nameInfo = String.valueOf(holder.getLayoutPosition());
            nameInfoFinal = stations.get(Integer.parseInt(nameInfo)).getName();
            String img;
            img = String.valueOf(holder.getLayoutPosition());
            dialog5 = new MaterialStyledDialog.Builder(PlayerView.favoriteAdd.getContext())
                    .setTitle(nameInfoFinal) // Название 
                    .setHeaderDrawable(R.drawable.playerview)
                    .setIcon(holder.iconView.getDrawable())
                    .setDescription(descriptionInfoFinal) // Описание 
                    .withDialogAnimation(false, Duration.FAST)
                    .withIconAnimation(true)
                    .setPositiveText("OK")
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                            dialog5.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public long getItemId(final int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stations.size();
}

private List<Station> getStations() {
    if (mode == MODE_FAVORITES) {
        return Favorites.getFavorites();
    }
    return ArrayListMain.getStations();
}

public void showFavorites() {
    mode = MODE_FAVORITES;

    updateStations();
}

public void showDirectory() {
    mode = MODE_DIRECTORY;
    updateStations();
}

public void setListener(final Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}


public void filterStations(final String query) {
    List<Station> filteredStations = queryStations(query);
    updateStations(filteredStations);
}

public void updateStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    removeFilteredStations(filteredStations);
    addFilteredStations(filteredStations);
}

public void updateStations() {
    updateStations(getStations());
}

private void removeFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    final Iterator<Station> iterator = stations.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final Station station = iterator.next();
        if (!filteredStations.contains(station)) {
            final int position = stations.indexOf(station);
            iterator.remove();
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
}

private void addFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    for (Station station : filteredStations) {
        if (!stations.contains(station)) {
            final int position = findPosition(station);
            stations.add(position, station);
            notifyItemInserted(position);

        }
    }
}

private int findPosition(final Station station) {

    int position = 0;
    while(position < stations.size() && stations.get(position).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(station.getName()) < 0) {
        position++;
    }
    return position;
}

private List<Station> queryStations(final String query) {
    final List<Station> filtered = new java.util.ArrayList();

    final boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(query);
    for (Station station : getStations()) {
        if (isEmpty || station.matchesQuery(query))
            filtered.add(station);
    }
    return filtered;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView iconView;
    TextView nameView, genre, online;
    //TextView descriptionView;
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        iconView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        nameView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        //descriptionView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        genre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        online = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.onlineView);
    }
}}
```

**код активити, в котором показывается RecyclerView:**

```
public class Genre_NewYear extends AppCompatActivity implements

    View.OnClickListener,
    Adapter_NewYear.Listener,
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    PlayerView.Listener {

...

private RecyclerView directory;
private PlayerView playerView;
public Adapter_NewYear adapter;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_genre);
    directory = findViewById(R.id.directory);
    directory.setHasFixedSize(true);
    directory.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 5, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    directory.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(directory.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    }
    adapter = new Adapter_NewYear();
    directory.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setListener(this);
...
}

...

private void showDirectory() {
    adapter.showDirectory();
}

...

}
```

**код коллекции Favorites:**

```
public class Favorites {

    public static ArrayList<String> favoriteUrls = null;
    private static File getFavoritesPath() {
        return new File(CacheManager.getRoot(), "favorites");
    }

    public static void load() {
        try {
            Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).load(new Sack.Listener<String[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(final Sack.Status status, final String[] favorites) {
                    favoriteUrls = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (favorites == null)
                        return;
                    favoriteUrls.addAll(Arrays.asList(favorites));
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Station> getFavorites() {
        final List<Station> favorites = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String url : favoriteUrls)
            favorites.add(ArrayListMain.getStation(url));
        Station.sort(favorites);
        return favorites;
    }

    public static void addFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
        if (!favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
            favoriteUrls.add(favoriteUrl);
            commit();
        }
    }

    public static void removeFavorite(final String favoriteUrl) {
        if (favoriteUrls.contains(favoriteUrl)) {
            favoriteUrls.remove(favoriteUrl);
            commit();
        }
    }

    private static void commit() {
        final String[] urls = favoriteUrls.toArray(new String[favoriteUrls.size()]);
        Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).commit(urls);
    }
}
```

**код основной коллекции (точно такой же):**

```
public class ArrayListMain {

    //private static final String TAG = Log.buildTag(Directory.class);
    private static List<Station> stations = null;

    private static Map<String, Station> stationIndex = new HashMap<>();

    public static void loadStations(final Context context) {
        stations = new ArrayList<>();

        final AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

        String paths[] = new String[0];
        try {
            paths = assetManager.list("stations");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "error loading stations", e);
            return;
        }

        for (String path : paths) {
            if (!path.endsWith(".json"))
                continue;
            final Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Station>>() {}.getType();
            List<Station> chunk = null;
            try {
                chunk = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("stations/" + path), "UTF-8"), listType);
                stations.addAll(chunk);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "error loading station: %s", e, path);
            }
        }

        Station.sort(stations);

        indexStations(stations);

    }

    private static void indexStations(final List<Station> stations) {
        stationIndex.clear();

        for (Station station : stations) {
            stationIndex.put(station.getStationUrl(), station);
        }
    }

    public static List<Station> getStations() {
        return stations;
    }

    public static Station getStation(final String url) {
        return stationIndex.get(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Откуда берутся данные для `RecyclerView`? Что делают методы `Favorites.getFavorites()` и `ArrayListMain.getStations()`?

Comment: Метод `Favorites.getFavorites()` получает объекты из коллекции избранного. То есть из `ArrayList<String>`. Точно такая же коллекция есть , как раз в которой находятся все объекты `List<Station>`

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Загружать json из файла из assets порционно, довольно нетривиальная и сложно реализуемая задача. Лучше просто вынесите загрузку в отдельный поток (если ещё не сделали) и показывайте пользователю какой нибудь прогрес бар. 2 секунды подождать один раз не очень критично, как по мне.

Comment: @eugeneek, так я перемещаюсь часто между коллекциями, когда хочу чтоб показалось либо коллекция с Избранным либо со всем списком.

Comment: в активити, по кнопке вызываю метод либо `showDirectory();` либо `showFavorites();` . По этому подвисает при выборе кнопки со всеми объектами.